# HTML Iframe Video in webview not playing

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to make an video application that get video from api in **JSON format** as **HTML iframe**. This iframe have not youtube videos its from my own payed server. Everything is working fine but when i click on the poster of the video it gives me an **videoError** and stop.

```
String yourData = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="https://crickethighlights9.com/services.brid.tv/player/build/brid.min.js"></script></head><body><iframe style="border: 0px #ffffff none;" src="https://services.brid.tv/services/iframe/video/378439/12215" name="CricketHighlights9" width="600px" height="400px" frameborder="1" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" __idm_frm__="424" __idm_id__="1052194817"></iframe></body></html>
```

[Here is an image of first load poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVaDJ.png)

[After Clicking On Poster Play Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sezdQ.png)

Comment: Can you provide a clean string?

Comment: Now its Cleaned!

Comment: I guess you are using IE is that correct? I've tried it on Jsfiddle and it appears to be working

Comment: I want to run this Code in **Android WebView** to play that video. Its Working fine in any Browser but its not working in android WebView. I run this code in WebView it shows video poster but when i click on it to play it gave me video Error.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it in the fiddle and it seems to be working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://crickethighlights9.com/services.brid.tv/player/build/brid.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe style="border: 0px #ffffff none;" src="https://services.brid.tv/services/iframe/video/378439/12215"
        name="CricketHighlights9" width="600px" height="400px" frameborder="1" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px"
        scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" __idm_frm__="424" __idm_id__="1052194817">
    </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want to run this Code in Android WebView to play that video. Its Working fine in any Browser but its not working in android WebView. I run this code in WebView it shows video poster but when i click on it to play it gave me video Error.